# How do I invoke wp-admin on localhost

Tags: wp-admin

I have a local installation of wordpress at c:\xampp\htdocs\qbneb. ordinary user runs on localhost, but when I switch to wp-admin, I get live website at https:\www.qbneb.com.  How do I make wp-admin run on localhost only?